# Get Android default edit text preference dialog layout

Tags: android, android-preferences

I've got an preference screen with android:dialogLayout="@layout/my_own_layout"

I would like to make my own dialogLayout look almost exactly like the default one, only with some minor changes (adjusting the spaces between title and summary).

Is there any way I can get the default layout? With the text sizes, paddings and so on?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always check the default layouts in different platforms and you can modify them.

For instance you can access the alert dialog layout in the following path:

`android-sdk\platforms\android-15\data\res\layout\`

for Android API LvL 15.

You can search for other api levels anytime to check different layouts there.

Comment: Yes! This is it, now I get it... thank you very much for the directions :)